# How do I iterate over a list and pass the funciton result to the next iteration

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and in an effort to learn, thought it would be fun to implement a clustering algorithm. 
I have an input list of lists that I need to iterate over. For each of these input vectors I need to apply a function that updates the weights and returns a list of lists (weight matrix). I can do that part via the `newMatrix` function. The problem is, I need to use the updated weight matrix in the next iteration, and I'm lost as to how to do this. Here's the important parts, some functions left out for brevity.

```
let inputList = [[1; 1; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 1]; [1; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 1; 1;]]
let weights = [[.2; .6; .5; .9]; [.8; .4; .7; .3]]
let newMatrix xi matrix =
    List.map2( fun w wi ->
        if wi = (yiIndex xi) then (newWeights xi)
        else w) matrix [0..matrix.Length-1]
 printfn "%A" (newMatrix inputList.Head weights)
 > >
 [[0.2; 0.6; 0.5; 0.9]; [0.92; 0.76; 0.28; 0.32]]
```

So my question is, how do I iterate over `inputList` calculating `newMatrix` for each inputVector using the previous `newMatrix` result?

**Edit: added psuedo algorithm:**

```
for input vector 1
    given weight matrix calculate new weight matrix
    return weight matirx prime
for input vector 2
    given weight matrix prime calculate new weight matrix
and so on...
...
```

Aside: I'm implementing a [Kohonen SOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map#cite_note-KohonenMap-0) algorithm fom [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133341860) book.

Comment: @Ankur & @Tomas I had a typo in the question that threw you guys off. I was referencing `newWeights` in the description and I should have been referencing `newMatrix`.  Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for List.fold.
Something like:

```
let inputList = [[1; 1; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 1]; [1; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 1; 1;]]
let weights = [[0.2; 0.6; 0.5; 0.9]; [0.8; 0.4; 0.7; 0.3]]
let newWeights w values = w //Fake method which returns old weight as it is
inputList |> List.fold (newWeights) weights
```

NOTE: The newWeights function in this case is taking weights and input vector and returns new weights

Or may be a List.scan in case you also need the intermediate calculated weights

```
let inputList = [[1; 1; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 1]; [1; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 1; 1;]]
let weights = [[0.2; 0.6; 0.5; 0.9]; [0.8; 0.4; 0.7; 0.3]]
let newWeights w values = w
inputList |> List.scan (newWeights) weights
```

Comment: Forgive me, I'm trying to figure out how to make my question clearer but it's complicated. I do need the intermediate calculated weights. Those intermediate weights then need to be the input for the next iteration.

Comment: @Nathan, thats what Fold function is for, i.e for each item in the list (in your case each vector in the list) calculate weights and then this calculated weight is used to calculate weight for next vector in the list and so on .. and in the end you will have a final single weight

Answer (score 5):

If you just started learning F#, then it may be useful to try implementing this explicitly using recursion first. As Ankur points out, this particular recursive pattern is captured by `List.fold`, but it is quite useful to understand how `List.fold` actually works. So, the explicit version would look like this:

```
// Takes vectors to be processed and an initial list of weights.
// The result is an adapted list of weights.
let rec processVectors weights vectors = 
  match vectors with
  | [] -> 
      // If 'vectors' is empty list, we're done and we just return current weights
      weights
  | head::tail -> 
      // We got a vector 'head' and remaining vectors 'tail'
      // Adapt the weights using the current vector...
      let weights2 = newweights weights head
      // and then adapt weights using the remaining vectors (recursively)
      processVectors weights2 tail
```

This is essentially what `List.fold` does, but it may be easier to understand it if you see the code written like this (the `List.fold` function hides the recursive processing, so the lambda function used as an argument is just the function that calculates new weights).

Aside, I don't quite understand your `newMatrix` function. Can you give more details about that? Generally, when working with lists you don't need to use indexing and it seems that you're doing something that requires accessing elements at a specific index. There may be a better way to write that....

Comment: The newMatrix function is the heart of the Kohonen algorithm, it essentially calculates a new weight matrix based on the weight with the minimum Euclidian distance. The vector that is the minimum replaces the original vector in the weight matrix, hence the indexing. I'm sure there's a better way, but as I said, I'm still a noob :D

Comment: This helped me understand how to put the algorithm in a recursive context. Thanks.